# global variables within functions changing across script sections in order to display a number

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use window.score within two different functions within two different scripts to make an updated score display when I click the button.

CRLF line endings

UTF-8 encoding

HTML grammar

newest version of firefox

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = window.score
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="score" style="position: absolute; bottom: 200px; visibility: hidden"></p>
<button type="button" style="position: absolute; bottom:50px;" onClick="submit();">Submit</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
function setElementVisible(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.visibility="visible";
}
function submit() {
  window.score = 0
  window.score += 10
  setElementVisible("score")
}
</script>
</body>
```

Expected: Button is clicked, the score appears as 10

Result: Button is clicked, the score does not appear at all

Comment: Values aren't automatically bound. The `innerHTML` property will not get updated just because you changed the `window.score` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As plalx mentioned in his comment, the `innerHtml` for the score element and `window.score` are not bound, because `window.score` passes by value. This means score's `innerHtml` is assigned to whatever `window.score` initially is (in this case, the actual score element as giving an element an id declares a global variable with that name), and doesn't change if `window.score` changes.

If you want the score element to reflect, you should assign its `innerHtml` to the new value of `window.score` once it changes (for example, on the `submit` function).

Btw, I think you are missing a curly brace in the first script.

Answer (score 0):

I think you still have 2 or something to learn

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title> Score </title>
  <style>
    #score {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 200px;
      visibility: hidden
    }
    #bt-Submit {
      position: absolute;
      bottom:50px;
    }
  </style>

  <script>
    window.onload = function() {

      var score = 0;
      const
        ElmScore = document.getElementById('score'),
        btSubmit = document.getElementById('bt-Submit');

      ElmScore.textContent = score;

      btSubmit.onclick = function() {
        score += 10;
        ElmScore.textContent      = score;
        ElmScore.style.visibility = "visible";
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="score"></p>
  <button type="button" id="bt-Submit">Submit</button>
</body>
</html>
```